# gcc: error: –o: No such file or directory gcc: error: filename: No such file or directory gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-pthreads’

Tags: linux, gcc, pthreads

I am trying to compile a c file in linux using the command

```
gcc filename.c –o filename -Wall -Werror -pthreads -std=c99
```

I am getting the following error

```
gcc: error: –o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: filename: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-pthreads’
```

I have no idea why. Any solution?

Comment: Not sure why the first  two errors are occurring as those args look ok. But the last one is because it should be `-pthread` (no `s`).

Answer (score 5):

Did you copy paste? Your `-` in `-o` seems to be some unicode character:

```
>>> '–'.encode()
b'\xe2\x80\x93'
```

Try typing the dash manually. Your last error should be fixed by using `-pthread` instead of `-pthreads`

Comment: U+2013 is an EN DASH (see the [U2000 code chart](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf)).